# Can't start kylin on kerberized cluster

Tags: kerberos, cloudera-cdh, kylin

I have installed Kerberos and Sentry on the CDH cluster successfully (cm-5.8.4), now I need to use Apache Kylin to do some data analysis, but I can't start Kylin and install the `sample.sh`.  When I try to run `sh sample.sh`, I get this error message:

> 2017-08-02 14:44:44,805 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:java.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.4-
>   1.cdh5.8.4.p0.5/lib/hadoop/lib/native/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.4-
>   1.cdh5.8.4.p0.5/lib/hadoop/lib/native/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.4-
>   1.cdh5.8.4.p0.5/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.4-
>   1.cdh5.8.4.p0.5/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 2017-08-02 14:44:44,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp 2017-08-02 14:44:44,806 INFO  [main]
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client  environment:java.compiler= 2017-08-02
>   14:44:44,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:os.name=Linux 2017-08-02 14:44:44,806 INFO  [main]
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client  environment:os.arch=amd64 2017-08-02
>   14:44:44,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:os.version=3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 2017-08-02 14:44:44,806
>   INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client  environment:user.name=root
>   2017-08-02 14:44:44,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:user.home=/root 2017-08-02 14:44:44,806 INFO  [main]
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client 
>   environment:user.dir=/data1/apache-kylin-1.6.0-cdh5.7-bin 2017-08-02
>   14:44:44,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client 
>   connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 
>   watcher=hconnection-0x3cc79c020x0, quorum=localhost:2181,
>   baseZNode=/hbase 2017-08-02 14:44:44,823 INFO 
>   [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)]  zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening
>   socket connection to server  localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not
>   attempt to authenticate using SASL  (unknown error) 2017-08-02
>   14:44:44,829 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] 
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,
>   closing  socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
>   2017-08-02 14:44:45,934 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] 
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL 
>   (unknown error) 2017-08-02 14:44:45,935 WARN 
>   [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)]  zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0
>   for server null, unexpected error, closing  socket connection and
>   attempting reconnect

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or show me a guide to use Kylin on a kerberized cluster? Thanks!

The version of Kylin is apache-kylin-1.6.0-cdh5.7-bin.

Answer (score 0):

to install kylin on kerberized cluster is quiet simple.

### step 1. ensure you install kylin on a cdh gateway.

### step 2. setup the environment correctly.

```
 such as hadoop_home;hive_conf;hbase_conf etc.
```

### step 3. follow the install instruction on kylin website.

if you need more help, leave me a message , so i can show you more detailed documentation on the first 2 steps.